# cache json until a miss then refresh it?

Tags: javascript, json, http, caching

For my website I like to cache some data (its can get up to 1MB and maybe more). I'd like to cache the json until 1) It's a day or two old 2) A search failled and I'd like to update it (but not if its <5min old).

How would I do this? I was thinking of doing `$.get('/my.json?ts=TIME')` but I don't know if that will be it's own file or overwrite/update `/my.json`

Comment: For client-side caching, you probably want something like [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [indexeddb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). I haven't used either very much myself, so I'll leave a better-composed answer to someone more knowledgeable on it.

Comment: @TheJim01 I guess that's an option but maybe overkill. Also they might have a few KB limit so I may not be able to use it

Comment: `localstorage` and `sessionstorage` actually have a combined space limit of 10MB. `indexeddb` varies by browser, but at the lowest end, you're looking at 10MB on desktop, and 5MB on mobile. Even with those "limits," it can ask for permission to use more, up to half your hard drive in some cases. In other words: don't sweat it unless your data is in the multiple megabytes range.

Answer (score 0):

Like TheJim01 said, you could use localstorage or indexeddb. I think that most browsers will allow 1MB of data in either localstorage or indexeddb, but I don't have much person knowledge there. A quick google search seems to support this though.

If you want to rely on browser caching, I would propose an approach like this:

1. Server side set `Cache-Control: max-age=86400`. This will ensure it isn't cached for more than 1 day.
2. Keep a random key in localStorage. Every time you need to clear your cache you would just change this random key. Use it in your `$.get()` call.

Client side looks something like this::

```
var randomKey = localStorage.getItem('cacheKey');

if (!randomKey || forceUpdateCache) {
    randomKey = '' + Math.random();
    localStorage.setItem('cacheKey', randomKey);
}

$.get('/my.json?v=' + randomKey);
```

Hope that helps.

**Edit**: I forgot you didn't want to clear the cache if you last updated <5 minutes ago. To do this you could also have a `lastUpdated` localStorage key that you set every time you generate a new random key.